# Number of occupied inodes via Quota?

Tags: inode, quota

Using the `quota` command, what is the number of occupied inodes by you in your pool account home directory? Find them out, with what type of file how many inodes you occupy?

Comment: What does the output of the `quota` command show you? I'd start with that, along with the options available to that command. You can see them with this command: `quota --help`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't normally do someone else's homework; however `edquota` will tell you.

Comment: problem is i've tried via edquota. But i dont got premission for it. Thats where im hanging

Comment: If there are quotas on inodes then as @slm suggested is the best way to go. From the question, it assumes that there are.